# having problems with embeds

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a simple embed for a help command, but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .addField('some text')
 .setColor('#202225')
 .setFooter('`nothing to see here`');

message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Simply saying "does not work" is not enough. State the error you are getting

Answer (score 2):

[`addField()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField) requires two parameters: the name and value. Having only one/neither will return an error.

[image: example]